# clicking a tab on a page to alow selenium to scrape

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import os

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


url = 'https://www.fifa.com/fifaplus/en/match-centre/match/17/255711/285063/400128082?country=IE&wtw-filter=ALL'

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/paulc/Documents/Medium Football/chromedriver.exe",options=option)

# Scraping the data

HomeTeam = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/p").text
AwayTeam = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]").text
Result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]").text
```

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF26r.png)/main/div/div[3]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF26r.png)/div/div[4]")))
elem.click()

[image]

Hi Guys, I am looking to scrape the world cup data, I have managed to start it easily by getting the team names and scores. The in game statistics are housed in the stats tab in the image. So to start scraping them I need to be able to click on it with selenium and make the page active.

Am i missing something obvious and that this cannot be done through an xpath?

help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try this xpath `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'STATS')]"))).click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to click on "LINE UP" tab this can be done with the following XPath: `"//div[text()='LINE UP']"`. To click on "STATS" tab you can use this XPath: `"//div[text()='STATS']"`. So, Selenium code line can be as following:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='LINE UP']"))).click()
```

For the `LINE UP` tab and

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='STATS']"))).click()
```

for the `"STATS"` tab.
Also, you need to improve your locators. Very long absolute XPaths are very breakable.

Comment: thank you. now on to the scraping of the stats page :)

Comment: I have ran into some apparant follow on trouble

Comment: element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='STATS']")))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

Comment: it doesnt seem like the code is working on navigating me to the tab as driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[46]/div[1]/div[2]").text
returns 'Fifa World Cup' which is only present on the overview page

Comment: ah i have cookies to deal with

Comment: In case you need more help please let me know

Comment: so when i take off the headless option I actually see what chromedriver is doing, the code is working to go to the stats page but there is a cookies pop up that needs to be clicked first